# Why jsonDecode in Dart has no type and no documentation?

Tags: dart

As you can see in https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html, it has no type and no documentation. I don't know which methods I can invoke on the result neither I don't know which type to but on a parameter that should be a json object.

Why is Dart like this? And what are the advantages?

Comment: I think, IIRC, that it returns a map<string, dynamic>. But you should use json_annotation and codegen do decode anything reasonably complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does have documentation, and you are linking to it. 
If you want it to have *more* documentation, then that is reasonable. The returned value is admittedly not documented very well.

The function [`jsonDecode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) is a shorthand for [`json.decode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-convert/JsonCodec/decode.html), which again forwards to [`JsonDecoder.convert`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-convert/JsonDecoder/convert.html).

It returns a "JSON value" object which depends on the JSON source that it decodes.
A "JSON value" can be any of:
* `null`
* an `int`
* a `double`
* a `String`
* a `bool` (`true` or `false`)
* a `List<dynamic>` containing zero or more JSON values.
* a `Map<String, dynamic>` mapping keys to JSON values.

Those are also the same values that are accepted by the [`JsonEncoder`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-convert/JsonEncoder-class.html) which converts object structures to JSON strings.

Since these types have no common superclass other than `Object`, the function cannot have a return type which is more specific than `dynamic` or `Object`.

The chosen return type is `dynamic` because the `dynamic` type allows the receiver to optimistically call any member on the value. They might know that the value will always be a map, so they can just do `jsonParse(jsonSource)["key"]` to look up a value. Obviously, if the source was not a JSON object, that call will fail.

If you don't know which type the result is, you have to check:

```dart
var data = jsonDecode(jsonSource);
if (data is Map<String, dynamic>) {
  something something data["key"] something
} else if (data is List<dynamic>) {
  something something list[2] something
} else ... etc ...
```

A valid JSON file is actually a valid Dart expression too. The value returned by `jsonDecode` is similar to the value you would get if you wrote the JSON code directly as Dart code (in Dart 1 it was exactly the same, in Dart 2, the Dart code might infer a more precise type for maps and lists).